# Unable to import functions in Python

Tags: python, airflow

Trying to resolve some packages >= Python 3.3

```
├── dags
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── aws.py
│   │   ├── conf.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── metamorph.py
│   │   └── sensor.py
│   ├── global.cfg
│   ├── dag_1
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── configuration
│   │   │   └── config.json
│   │   ├── dag
│   │   │   ├── 
│   │   │   └── test.py
```

in `test.py` I'm trying to import things from `common`, but unable to get it resolved. I've print things on the `sys.path` but not seeing any conf in there. What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you running your script from? What's the path you're using? `python test.py`?

Comment: correct, running `test.py` from the location of test.py

Comment: Is this an apache airflow project?

Comment: yes it is, so probably run into more issues after I get this working locally